# Reading Output from cmd asynchronously

Tags: vb.net

I'm using this code:

```
Shared sb_OutputData As New StringBuilder()
Shared sb_ErrorData As New StringBuilder()
Shared proc As Process = Nothing

Private Sub cmd()
    If proc IsNot Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim info As New ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe")

    ' Redirect the standard output of the process.

    info.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    info.RedirectStandardInput = True
    info.RedirectStandardError = True

    ' Set UseShellExecute to false for redirection

    info.UseShellExecute = False
    proc = New Process
    proc.StartInfo = info

    ' Set our event handler to asynchronously read the sort output.

    AddHandler proc.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf proc_OutputDataReceived
    AddHandler proc.ErrorDataReceived, AddressOf proc_ErrorDataReceived

    proc.Start()

    ' Start the asynchronous read of the sort output stream. Note this line!
    proc.BeginOutputReadLine()
    proc.BeginErrorReadLine()

End Sub

Private Shared Sub proc_ErrorDataReceived(sender As Object, e As DataReceivedEventArgs)
    'Console.WriteLine("Error data: {0}", e.Data)
    sb_ErrorData.AppendLine(e.Data)
End Sub

Private Shared Sub proc_OutputDataReceived(sender As Object, e As DataReceivedEventArgs)
    '   Console.WriteLine("Output data: {0}", e.Data)
    sb_OutputData.AppendLine(e.Data)
End Sub

Sub CmdWrite(arguments As String)
    Dim writeStream As StreamWriter = proc.StandardInput
    writeStream.WriteLine(arguments)
End Sub
```

It works exactly as I want, be able to retrieve cmd output and error data without closing it (and asynchronously), however, I'm not able to know when the command is finished executing. I'd like to know when it reaches the end of the stream for me to grab all the output and do something with it...

I've been searching for quite long, and can't find an answer to this.
Help please?

Comment: use `WaitForExit()` , may be

Comment: I need the cmd to keep running, i need to run more commands, and closing it everytime wouldn't fit my needs... any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stream is open is long as the command window is open. You can't tell when they stop or start. If the command you're running doesn't indicate its end with a unique/detectable pattern, you're stuck, unless you can edit the script you're running and insert a string - which you can't guarantee won't show in the normal output - in between the command calls.

Comment: Thanks for the info, i was afraid of this, there should be something along with BeginOutputReadline that could tell the stream reached to an "end" or something, but i understand why now... gonna have to think for another way of doing this, thanks.